# Configure ember-cli production build with sourcemaps to different domain

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

I'd like to configure the ember-cli build in a way that I'm able to change the URL for the sourcemaps. In production I only want to make them available for members inside the private network.

I can already get those sourcemap-files to the desired location.

The sourcemap reference at the bottom of the minified js files has to change from `//# sourceMappingURL=app-cfe74707c5fabd05465ffc575495dc46.map` to `//# sourceMappingURL=http://localhost/sourcemaps/app-cfe74707c5fabd05465ffc575495dc46.map`

Is there an ability to change it in the [ember-cli config](https://ember-cli.com/asset-compilation) or do I have to use something like [ember-cli-deploy](http://ember-cli-deploy.com)?